# Inline search box form with input group dropdown - problems with text input width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do seach box like this:

[image]

What's the best way of doing it with bootstrap?.

I was playing with inline form and input group dropdown list, but I have problems with text input width, as it's not fills out whole page width.

http://www.bootply.com/LRUm7PdeMN

Comment: So you want to occupy full page width with this search-bar ?

Comment: Yes, full page width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking the snippet..

Rest of styling you can do yourself..

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="search-box">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Search ...">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">All categories <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Wszystkie kategorie</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <!-- /btn-group -->
            </div>
            <!-- /input-group -->
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```